# Initialize a session var as array in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to initialize a session var as array.
Where i do that?

when i try to do this:

```
session[:complains_id] << params[:id]
```

i get this message

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>   You might have expected an instance of Array.
>   The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<

I know that i have to initialize the var but i dont know where.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just do:

```
  (session[:complains_id] ||= []) << params[:id]
```

Which is saying:

1. if `session[:complains_id]` returns
   nil, set it to [].
2. Append
   `params[:id]` to
   `session[:complains_id]`

Demo:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > (session[:complains_id] ||= []) << 5
 => [5] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 > (session[:complains_id] ||= []) << 3
 => [5, 3] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009 > (session[:complains_id] ||= []) << 1
 => [5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: How can i take an element our of the array?

Comment: But when i render the session[:id], i get the following: "35313131". The elements are not separated or anything.